# QtCreator BareMetal plugin - Failed to activate protocol version: "CMAKE_GENERATOR" is set but incompatible with configured generator value

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, bare-metal

I recently ran into the problem that I can't build a project using QtCreator with the BareMetal plugin using CMake and Makefiles.
QtCreator looses connection to the CMaker server and prints the following error message:

> Fehler: Failed to activate protocol version: "CMAKE_GENERATOR" is set
>   but incompatible with configured generator value.

I can run CMake if I configure the Kit to use NMake instead, but I need to generate Makefiles.

The problem must be related with a recent update of QtCreator and its usage of cmake in "pipe" mode.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Once I got that issue I deleted all CMakeFiles in build folder and run CMake again.  My problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but before that QtCreator confessed it is trying to run the following command:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E server --pipe=/tmp/cmake-.RLKKYt/socket --experimental
```

So I ran it and the resulting error pointed me to check if `/tmp/cmake-.RLKKYt` exists. Which it didn't. So I manually created it. And the problem was fixed. Temporarily, for sure.